# What are the different versions of exec used for in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, exec

These are all the versions of exec that can be used in C (and C++)

```
execl
execle
execlp
execv
execve
execvp
```

What's the difference between them? How do you know which one to use?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

The differences are combinations  of:

1. **L vs V**: whether    you want to pass the     parameters to       the exec'ed    program as

   - **L**: individual parameters in the call (variable argument list): `execl()`, `execle()`, `execlp()`, and `execlpe()`
   - **V**: as    an array of char* `execv()`, `execve()`, `execvp()`, and `execvpe()`

   The array       format is    useful when the number of     parameters that are to be sent to    the    exec'ed process are variable    -- as in    not known in advance, so you can't       put in a fixed    number of parameters      in a    function call.
2. **E**: The versions with an 'e' at the end let you additionally pass an    array of char* that are a set of        strings added to the spawned     processes environment before the     exec'ed program launches.  Yet    another way of passing parameters,    really.
3. **P**: The versions with 'p' in there use the environment variable `PATH`
   to    search for the executable file    named     to execute. The versions    without the     'p' require an    absolute or relative      file path    to be prepended to the     filename of the executable if it is     not in the current working    directory.

Answer (score 5):

Opengroup are one of the best general references for core c/c++ functions.

The docs for exec* are here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/environ.html

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question and is link only.

Comment: Before arriving here, I read the documentation on the website, but it did not help a lot. The explanations are very short, even though they should be elaborate. Additionally, it is hard to find the correct explanation for what you are looking for, if you are searching from scratch.

Answer (score -5):

It's Posix extension of C runtime library. If official Posix documentation is insufficiently then I can recomend book - Samuel P. Harbison, Guy L.Steele, 2002 "C A Reference" Page# 416 - cover that question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18249709)

Comment: The links was to amazon and to posxis standart to be usefull for reader. Ok, I removed links as you asked, even I disagree that this is better. Remve your donwvote if now it's more readable.

Comment: I didn't downvote for your answer. I just had my review on your answer, which I thought was of low quality. I didn't mean to remove the links. The point here is to include relevant excerpts from the link which helps the future readers to understand the answer instantly. Just posting the links in the answer doesn't help anyone.