# What is the difference between execl and execv?

Tags: c, linux, exec

I use `execv` instead of `execl`. To use `execv`, I create an array and put arguments that I use with `execl` in there. Then I put this array into `execv`

I know I have to use an array of arguments for `execv` but why? What is the difference between `execl` and `execv`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the different versions of exec used for in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5769734/608639)

Answer (score 14):

There is no difference other than the format of the arguments.  They will both end up calling the same underlying system call `execve()`.

Comment: Why do we need the change the format of the arguments? I mean if they are doing same thing

Comment: The `execve()` system call (and `execv()`) take the arguments in an array.  `execl()` is just provided as a convenience, in case you have a fixed number of arguments, to allow you to avoid the trouble of setting up an array.  `execl()` will store the function arguments in a temporary array itself and then make the system call.  If you set up the argument array yourself then you have no need for `execl()`.

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32142863